# Como crear los enunciados para recorrer un árbol generico, (no binario) en Prolog?

Tags: prolog, genericos, swi-prolog

Crear los enunciados para recorrer un arbol generico en:

-Preorden
-Inorden
-Postorden

Tengo el recorrido preorden que seria el siguiente en prolog, este recorrido lo encontré en la web, pero al ser nuevo en prolog no entiendo como desarrollar el recorrido inorden y el postoden en arboles genericos.

Tengo:

```
preorden(a(X,Xs),[X|Ys]) :- preorden(Xs,Ys).
preorden([],[]).
preorden([X|Xs],Zs) :- preorden(X,Y), preorden(Xs,Ys), append(Y,Ys,Zs).
```

como resultado de este arbol generico:

```
arbolg( a(a,[a(f,[a(g,[])]),a(c,[]),a(b,[a(d,[]),a(e,[])])]) ).
```

seria:

```
?- arbolg(A), preorden(A,R).
A = a(a, [a(f, [a(g, [])]), a(c, []), a(b, [a(d, []), a(e, [])])]),
R = [a, f, g, c, b, d, e].
```

gracias de antemano por este tema.